# Problem with mocking - Null Pointer Exception when trying to mock external API method

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm trying to test the class:

```
public class WeatherProvider {

private OWM owm;

public WeatherProvider(OWM owm) {
    this.owm = owm;
}

public CurrentWeatherData getCurrentWeather(int cityId) throws APIException, UnknownHostException {

    CurrentWeatherData currentWeather = new CurrentWeatherData(owm.currentWeatherByCityId(cityId));

    return currentWeather;

}

public HourlyWeatherForecastData getHourlyWeather(int cityId) throws APIException, UnknownHostException {

    HourlyWeatherForecastData hourlyWeather = new HourlyWeatherForecastData(owm.hourlyWeatherForecastByCityId(cityId));

    return hourlyWeather;

}
```

}

OWM is an external API so I want to mock it. I wrote a test method:

```
    @Test
void shouldReturnCurrentWeather() throws APIException, UnknownHostException {
    //given
    OWM owm = mock(OWM.class);
    WeatherProvider weatherProvider = new WeatherProvider(owm);
    int cityId = 123;
    CurrentWeather currentWeather = WeatherDataStub.getCurrentWeather();
    given(owm.currentWeatherByCityId(cityId)).willReturn(currentWeather);

    //when
    CurrentWeatherData currentWeatherData = weatherProvider.getCurrentWeather(cityId);

    //then

}
```

I get a java.lang.NullPointerException in given().willReturn() line and I don't know why. I want to test cases when owm.currentWeatherByCityId(cityId) succesfuly returns CurrentWeather object (which is a stub class in this case) or throws exceptions.
Can you explain to me what I do wrong?

Comment: When you put breakpoint on the problematic line and run the test in debug, which variable is `null`? `owm`, `currentWeather`(but that shouldn't be a problem), or perhaps the expression `given(owm.currentWeatherByCityId(cityId))`?

Comment: currentWeather is not null. owm is "Mock for OWM, hashCode..." but every field of the object is null (like apiKey, language, baseURL and so on). When I added given() expression to the watch list it said "Method threw NullPointerExcepion". I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: I think its the given() expression which is null.

Comment: Look like some kind of misconfiguration of Mockito then. Do you have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on the test class?

Comment: If you put mockito's `any()`, `anyInt()` or `eq(cityId)` instead of `cityId` in the problematic line, does it solve the NPE?

Comment: I use JUnit5 so the annotation RunWith is replaced with ExtendWith, but IDE doesnt allow me to extend the test class with MockitoJUnitRunner.class. The compiler says "java: cannot access org.junit.runner.Runner
  class file for org.junit.runner.Runner not found"

Comment: No. I tried to use any(), anyInt() methods before and the problem doesn't disappear.

Comment: What's more in console it says that the Exceptions also was thown " at net.aksingh.owmjapis.core.OWM.currentWeatherByCityId"
Should it be able to be thrown in the external API library if the OWM object is correctly mocked?